# Restrict other Azure AD users from logging into Intune devices

Tags: microsoft-intune, restrictions

I want to make sure that a user in our domain john.doe@xyz.com does not login to a device that has been assigned to don.king@xyz.com. I have created a configuration profile but not sure what the settings should be and the string value to be for such kind of situation.

Any suggestions and answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Allow Local Log On** and **Deny Local Log On** rights from **User Rights** category from **Settings Catalog** to the Configuration Profile you created

Username format is `AzureAD\user1@contoso.com`

Details are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-userrights#userrights-allowlocallogon